# How to change theme on code blocks under ubuntu

Tags: themes, ubuntu-14.04, codeblocks

How to change color theme on Code Blocks under Ubuntu 14.04? I want to import highlighting syntax from official web-site, but I can't find the colour_themes.conf.

Answer (score 4):

```
First you have to close CB
Then run sudo cb_share_config
Find default.conf under .codeblocks where you installed it // Almost home folder for destination folder
Finally you have to select source folder that created for themes
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vladyslav: You can go to [this page](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Syntax_highlighting_custom_colour_themes)  then scroll down and look for the Installation section. The xml content is the content of the file colour_themes.conf itself.